# Why do none of my Pikachu have the option to evolve into Raichu?

Tags: pokemon-go

Why do none of my Pikachu have the option to evolve into Raichu in Pokemon Go? I understand the event Pokemon aren't able to be evolved. However, I have regular Pikachu as well, and none of them have the option to evolve. My daughter has a lower trainer level than I do but she has the option for her Pikachu. I've even tried re-installing the game. Any advice would help.

Answer (score 23):

The clone Pikachu, available through the photobomb from  February 26th until 2nd of March 2020, was also not able to evolve. They have a different black marking on their ears, as shown in the following picture (clone on the right):

[image: Normal Pikachu vs Clone Pikachu]

Probably you are trying to evolve one of these, which is not possible. You should be able to evolve non-event/non-clone Pikachus. One that you obtain today (or a non-event caught before the photobomb-clone-event), would be evolve-able to Raichu.

Comment: *Edits your image to reference mine, and my image to reference yours*

Comment: i don't think this fixes their problem, because they say themselves that; "I understand the event Pokemon aren't able to be evolved. However, I have regular Pikachu as well, and none of them have the option to evolve."

Comment: It's because this photobomb Pikachu looks a lot like a normal one, whereas event Pikachu have distinctive hats. That's the only explanation so far.

Answer (score 16):

These are Event Pokemon.

Event Pokemon (at this point in time) do not have anything special about them, other then appearance, and potentially a special move. The most recent versions of the Event Pikachus either wear a party hat, or are ["Clone" Pikachus](https://www.gamerevolution.com/guides/faqs/635846-clone-pikachu-vs-regular-differences), as part of the Armored Mewtwo Event.

[image: Clone vs Regular Pikachu]

The main difference is that the Clone Pikachus have a zigzag black tip on each ear, and cannot be evolved. The normal Pikachus have a flat black tip on each ear, and can be evolved.

This is a part of the [Pokemon Day](https://pokemongolive.com/en/post/pokemonday2020/) event, that celebrates the re-release of the Mewtwo Strikes Back movie on Netflix.

> **Remember Clone Pokémon?** Well, some are coming to Pokémon GO! In celebration of the Pokémon Day launch of Pokémon: Mewtwo Strikes Back—Evolution on Netflix, special Clone Pokémon — including Venusaur, Charizard, and Blastoise — will appear in four-star raids. Be sure to use #GOsnapshot during the event, too — Clone Pikachu might appear in your photo, and you might be able to catch it!

These are specific to the "Character" Pokemon from the movie; the reason why this Clone Pikachu doesn't have an evolution is because it is modeled after Ash's Pikachu, that *never* evolves throughout the entire Pokemon series.

Comment: Ghehe, we even used the exact same image :D